# How to append fields to published node in drupal?

Tags: entities, nodes

A node once published should not be edited, but extra fields can be added to that node. How can i do it? For example , lets say i have a content type called 'employee'. Once i create this content i cannot edit that node but can only add more information to that node. this extra information must be stored in the node's column. Is it possible ? or is there any other way?

Comment: What do you mean be "cannot be edited"? Just go to `node/NODE_ID/edit`.

Comment: oh..sorry.. 'should not be edited' !

Comment: If you don't want to "edit" it (generally speaking) you will not be able to change its content. Why they shouldn't be edited?

Answer (score 1):

guess its possible with a combination of [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6) and [hook_nodeapi](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6)

Do check out these methods... hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

Ah, just hit me - I think I know what you could have in mind - kind of "locking" some fields, so that their values cannot be edited once they are saved, still though users could provide values for other fields, is that it?

If that's the case, have you looked at [Field Permissions](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) and [Workflow Fields](http://drupal.org/project/workflow_fields) modules?